# Set publicPath to an environment variable value

Tags: vue.js

In my vue.config.js file I have publicPath set to `'/ui'`

I would like to set that to be `ui` unless there is an environment variable in which case it should use that value.

I've read through the env mode docs and also see you can have computed variables in config.js but I can't quite get it working.

```
//docs say i can read an envvar here     

module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/ui',
  outputDir: '../myapp/wwwroot',
  assetsDir: undefined,
  runtimeCompiler: undefined,
  productionSourceMap: undefined,
  parallel: undefined,
  css: undefined
}
```

Comment: It would be `publicPath: process.env.YOUR_ENV_VAR || '/ui'`. Is that not working as you expect it too?

Comment: That did it, can't work out what was going wrong